# How to add a random number after a link

Tags: javascript

I have a link and I want to add a random number after this link every time that page is load.

How can I do this?

Is there a way to add random number in href tag without any separate jquery code?

i wrote the below code but it does not work.

```
<a href="secondpage?rand=+Math.Random()">click</a>
```

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript by modifying the value of `href` on the `a` tag by using `Math.random`.

Comment: What server-side language are you using? You may be approaching this incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant just mix in javascript somewhere on your page. It must be inside a certain area, e.g. the *onclick* property:

```
<a onclick="location.href = `secondpage?rand=${Math.random()}`">click</a>
```

Because this is usually a bad idea, we could have a script that modifies all links on the page and adds the random number:

```
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(link =>
      link.href += "?rand=" + Math.random()
    );
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This will make all links absolute. If you don't wan't this you should better use `link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href") + '?rand=' + Math.random())`. Also you should add a logic to avoid two questionmarks in the url if it already has a query string.

Comment: how can i select link with specific class ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".class")` or `document.getElementsByClassName("class")`. Then you can iterate over it with a loop.

Comment: @JonasW. querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList which doesnt implement the `forEach`-method.

Edit:

Ok it seems they implemented it for a NodeList :) 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @JonasW. Thank you so much

Comment: @aynaz, see my question above. You're very likely going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @james still no need to spam someone... Maybe the OP has no server yet at all

Comment: @aynaz glad to help ;)

Comment: @JonasW., relax :-). Two comments isn't spam. I'm simply trying to help, not just get rep without asking questions. That's what SO is for, right? Learning, interaction, and helping each other become better? Chill.

Comment: @james thats how SO *should* be... :/

Comment: Will probably be crucified for this but when I need to make adjustments to one specific element, I normally select based on an ID instead of classname, for future compatibility. From your question it appears you’re only modifying one element of the DOM, where this would be appropriate (and faster).

Comment: @tony D well i prefer flexibility over performance ( which doesnt really matter here)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for random number generation is `Math.random()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

In order to assign the *random number* to the *href* manipulate the *DOM*.

**Here is an example:**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="foo"> </div>
  <script>
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href="secondpage?rand="+Math.random();
    a.innerText = "click";
    var div = document.getElementById('foo');
    div.appendChild(a);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but how can I use this after a link?